# How to force reload if anything changes in JS while user is browsing in between partials

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

In my angular app, there is:

- index.html: which holds all statics like js and css and a ng-view tag, which loads all the partials.
- partials: which are loaded in ng-view as and when user reaches out.

So I am in/have confusion/doubt/issue, regarding a scenario, what if I change something in my controllers and compile will it get served again in the immediate new partials request to my server out of the box? if no what changes or configuration changes do I make to match it with the expectation.
Otherwise there is always a chance of broken experience, where partial is updated but js is old till user himself refreshes it.

PS: I am new to web-development and still learning these details.

Comment: do you mean you'd update your server one file at a time? wouldn't you redeploy all at once? what deployment tool/method are you using

Comment: @atmd on server I am using Nodejs, if I change controllers I will just upload the the minified js files. shouldn't it be like this? why to deploy all the htmls and css again if change is in js only, though I am deploying all js files (minified).? please let me know if I am missing something here.

Comment: by automatically redeploying each file on change, you'll likely (dependent on traffic) hit sync issues, you'd be better off (imho) uploading all updated files at a point where you are happy

Comment: logically we will arrive at that approach only, but the problem remains still.

Answer (score 0):

If you update a partial and push that update into production, whenever your app now requests that partial (*through user interaction via the app or a page reload*) it will be the updated version.  However if you update your angular app file, that change will not be displayed to the user until they refresh the page, because that resource has already been loaded by the browser and the browser has no way of knowing that the file has been changed and needs to be reloaded.

The reason the partials will appear updated is because your Angular app is sending http requests to get each one.  The app cannot send a request to get a new version of itself (nor should it).

Comment: I tested this scenario before posting and it was not loading my JS while moving along partials, but was not sure this should be the behaviour and I am not asking will partial update or not it will definitely be updated, what I was asking is about the JS files which I have loaded in index.html with other static resources like CSS (is it the right place?). I am not sure about your hardcoded part what did you meant by that?

Comment: Ah so in your index.html you have something like `<script src="js/angularApp.js"></script>`, right?

Comment: Yes, so what do you mean when you say those are not loading whie 'moving along partials'?

Comment: when I load next partials using $location.path() say on press of some "Next" button it doesn't load my new JS. as its defined in index.html.

Comment: Yes so as I stated above, loading the next partials will not affect the angularApp.js which has already been fetched by the browser.  If you update angularApp.js, the only way a user on your website would see the result is through a page reload.  It will not change by getting the next partial.

Comment: so its not possible? it may lead to broken experience?

Comment: If you are making frequent and significant changes to your angular application in a production environment, that may lead to a poor user experience by itself.  If you need such an environment, creating at least one other page that is not a partial and will get a full http request will allow the angular app to be reloaded whenever that page or index.html is visited.